# my jquery ajax doesnt seems to work in ie6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax in my project thats working good in my firefox But it  doesnt seem to work in IE6
How to make the jquery Ajax work in  Ie6
This is my code

```
function Load_State(inp)
{

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "<?=base_url()?>/system/application/views/ssitAjax.php",
   data: "selCurCountry="+inp,
   success: function(msg){
     //alert(  msg );
     document.getElementById('selCurState').innerHTML=msg;
   }
 });
} 
function Load_City(inp)
{

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "<?=base_url()?>/system/application/views/ssitAjax.php",
   data: "selCurState="+inp,
   success: function(msgq){
    //alert(  msgq );
     document.getElementById('selCurCity').innerHTML=msgq;
   }
 });
}
```

This is my ssit ajax page

```
<?php

include('dbConnection.php');

session_start();
if(($_GET['selCurCountry']!="") || (isset($_GET['selCurCountry'])))
{

             $Country = $_GET['selCurCountry'];
             $_SESSION['Country'] = $Country;

            $query = "SELECT dState_id,dStateName 
                            FROM tbl_state
                            WHERE dCountry_id='$Country'
                            AND dIsDelete='0'";


            $result = mysql_query($query,$cn) or die("Selection Query Failed !!!");

            echo '<option value="0">Select The State</option>';

            while($rowset = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
               echo "<option value='".$rowset[0]."'>".$rowset[1]."</option>";
             }

}
else if(($_GET['selCurState']!="") || (isset($_GET['selCurState'])))
{

            $State = $_GET['selCurState'];
            $_SESSION['state'] = $State;
            $query = "SELECT dCity_id,dCityName FROM tbl_city
                        WHERE dState_id='$State'
                        AND dIsDelete='0'";


            $result = mysql_query($query,$cn) or die("Selection Query Failed !!!");


            echo '<option value="0">Select The City</option>';

            while($rowset = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
               echo "<option value='".$rowset[0]."'>".$rowset[1]."</option>";
             }



}?>
```

EDIT:

```
 <option value="0">Select The State</option>
 <option value='1'>Andhra Pradesh</option><option value='2'>Arunachal Pradesh</option><option value='3'>Assam</option><option value='4'>Bihar</option><option value='5'>Chandigarh</option><option value='6'>Chhattisgarh</option><option value='7'>Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option><option value='8'>Daman and Diu</option><option value='9'>Delhi</option><option value='10'>Goa</option><option value='11'>Gujarat</option><option value='12'>Haryana</option><option value='13'>Himachal Pradesh</option><option value='14'>Jammu and Kashmir</option><option value='15'>Jharkhand</option><option value='16'>Karnataka</option><option value='17'>Kerala</option><option value='18'>Lakshadweep</option><option value='19'>Madhya Pradesh</option><option value='20'>Maharashtra</option><option value='21'>Manipur</option><option value='22'>Meghalaya</option><option value='23'>Mizoram</option><option value='24'>Nagaland</option><option value='25'>Orissa</option><option value='26'>Puducherry</option><option value='27'>Punjab</option><option value='28'>Rajasthan</option><option value='29'>Sikkim</option><option value='30'>Tamil Nadu</option><option value='31'>Tripura</option><option value='32'>Uttar Pradesh</option><option value='33'>Uttarakhand</option><option value='34'>West Bengal</option>
```

Comment: Any errors? Can you show the *parsed HTML* instead of the PHP source code?

Comment: On any Q&A site (like SO) or discussion forum where you're asking a question, whenever you find yourself typing *"But it doesnt seem to work..."*, backspace and say "But it does XYZ when I want it to do ABC" instead (or "But it doesn't do XYZ and I was expecting it to.") You get the idea. :-)

Comment: +1 for TJ, maybe your error is due to ie cache on ajax request ... you have to had a random number at the end of the query

Comment: object doesnt support this property or method ie this is the bug

Comment: Can you show some of the HTML?  I bet it's not finding the selector elements. (edit) You've added the `<option>` elements, but the *interesting* part would be the `<select>` elements.

Comment: Actually it works properly in firefox

Comment: @udaya see my answer below - I think that's what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wait a minute - I think I know what the problem is.  In IE6, you cannot just replace the "innerHTML" of `<select>` elements like that.  You have to rebuild the whole `<select>` from scratch.  (Or you can empty out the `options` array on the `<select>` elements and rebuild them with DOM APIs.)

Try wrapping the `<select>` elements in `<span>` tags (with "id" values) and then rebuild the "innerHTML" of those, adding the `<select>` elements again. That's a pain I know and it might mess up other stuff, but it'd be a good experiment to validate my suspicion.

Comment: @patrick that *might* work, but it'd depend on jQuery being smart enough to figure that out - perhaps it is!

Comment: Tested it *before* I posted the comment. :o)

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced PHP before but have had similar weirdness in IE with ajax/get/post calls.  Have you tried specifying content-type?

```
$.ajax({ url: "/home/myPage.aspx",
         type: "GET",
         data: { selCurrCountry: inp }, 
         content-type: "application/json",
         success: function(data) {
            alert("Yay!");
         }
});
```

Also, if you are needing that data value in the query string, why not just append it to the url and set data: {} or not at all?

```
$.ajax({ url: "/home/myPage.aspx?selCurCountry=" + inp,
         type: "GET",
         success: function(data) {
            alert("Yay!");
         }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I bet the Ajax part is working fine; it's working for him in Firefox after all.

Comment: Possibly.  But IE6 is a different beast in the javascript department.  I just wanted to offer a few suggestions.  I have seen weirdness like this before.